# Having different relationships in the same models in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm building a project where a user can create an event and joins many events, 
and the event has one owner but can have many users joined

Here are The methods in the Model Event.php

```
public function creator()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

Here are The methods in the Model User.php

```
public function createdEvents()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function joinedEvents()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class);
}
```

And here is the pivot table migration file

```
class CreateEventUserTable extends Migration
{
 /**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function up()
 {
   Schema::create('event_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->unsignedInteger('event_id');
       $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
       $table->timestamps();
       $table->primary(['event_id', 'user_id']);    

       $table->foreign('event_id')
           ->references('id')->on('events')
           ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('user_id')
           ->references('id')->on('users')
           ->onDelete('cascade');
   });
}
```

And here is the events migration

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('events', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
       $table->text('content');
       $table->date('date');
       $table->time('time');
       $table->unsignedSmallInteger('min_attendance');
       $table->unsignedSmallInteger('max_attendance');
       $table->string('location');
       $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');
       $table->timestamps();

       $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users')
           ->onDelete('cascade');
   });
}
```

I want to know where I did do wrong or if there s a problem in order to avoid future problems in retrieving data using Laravel Eloquent

Comment: Can you show the migration for the `events` table as well?

Comment: yes sure, I'll update the snippet

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the User model. The relation of createdEvents needs to be like this:

```
public function createdEvents()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should keep just one relation in your event model like this:

```
public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

And your user model like this:

```
public function events()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class);
}
```

And you could have a third model named `Subscription` and then make a relation table between events and users

```
public function up()
{
   Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->increments('id');
       $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
       $table->unsignedInteger('event_id');
       $table->timestamps();

       $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')->on('users')
           ->onDelete('cascade');

       $table->foreign('event_id')
        ->references('id')->on('events')
           ->onDelete('cascade');
   });
}
```

And finally the Subscription Model:

```
public function users()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

public function event()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
}
```

This way you could access all users that joined in your event with a query like this:

```
$joinedUsers = Subscription::where('event_id','=','$id')->pluck('user_id');
```